# smooth animation pixi.js on circle radius

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, pixi.js

I was wondering if it could be possible to do smooth animation on circles/sprites as I did for hits using D3.js over Leaflet

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10d5L_zR-MyQf1H9CLDg1wKcvnPQd5mvW/view?usp=sharing

With just some circles D3 works fine. Then, browser collapses.
I am completely new to Pixi.js, I guess it should be done changing the scale. I managed to change it, but not smoothly at all. There is something similar to D3.js for animating?

I am trying Leaflet.PixiOverlay plugin, using as a reference for coding [this example](https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay/blob/master/docs/french-cities.html)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Linear Interpolation:**

```
lerp = (a, b, c) => a * (1 - c) + b * c;
```

Use this while looping through `requestAnimationFrame`

```
circle.radius = lerp(circle.radius, /* Your Radius Here*/, 0.1);
```